# How to predict fault tolerance using Machine Learning Algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

[image: Machine Data Set]

Column 0, 1, 2, 3 are the four kinds of time series data. 
When the machine is normal it gives normal predictable data.
In faulty mode is quite different.
In failure mode is distinctly different, close to zero.

I need to predict when the machine is in fault mode and failure mode?

Answer (score 1):

I would use linear regression for this one.  It seems like you could just draw straight lines across multiple dimensions and be done with it.

Comment: What do you mean by discrete?  The values you posted seem continuous to me.  Also, you know more than I do about your machine, but from what I understand, the numbers behave differently when the machine is in danger.  Ignore the datetime column, and instead label each row as 0 or 1, normal or faulty.  If you would like to do failure mode too then you would do one-hot encoding, which I can tell you more about if you are interested.  Actually there’s a much much easier way to do this using AutoML.

Comment: [github code](https://github.com/varshinireddyt/Python-for-DataScience/blob/master/timeseries/Data_science_exercise.ipynb)

As you suggested i tried to do label encode. But how can I change values to 0 or 1.  can you look into the above github code and suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I would do.  Look at your Seaborn charts and see if you can divide the data into 3 distinct categories: normal, failing, and failed.  Then create 3 new columns with the headers Normal, Failing, and Failed.  If that row looks like the machine is operating normally, put a 1 in the Normal column.  If the next row looks like it’s failing, put a 1 in the Failed column, etc.